# Update & Delete Cursor Functions

Tags: arcpy, cursor, typeerror

In my program:

- I am selecting only schools of the specified type based on the "FACILITY" field and creating new feature class of the result.
- Deleting records from the resulting feature class from "Select" where the "Verified" field does not equal "Y" or "y" (I need to use: Update cursor and deleteRow method)
- For the records that do not equal "y" print the name of each deleted school

My code is not deleting the features that are not equal to "Y". And I am not sure how to print out the values that do not equal "Y".

Current error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 26, in 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 19, in selectSchools
TypeError: 'Row' object does not support indexing

```
import arcpy

work = arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\Scripts\Lab 6 Data"
sType = "JUNIOR HIGH"
outFile = "output.shp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def selectSchools(work,sType, outFile):
    fc = "Schools.shp"
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "schoolslyr")
    query = "\"FACILITY\" = '{0}'".format(sType)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, outFile, query)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Select_Analysis layer tool completed!")

    where_c = "\"VERIFIED\" = 'y%'"
    update = arcpy.UpdateCursor(outFile)
    row = update.next()
    for row in update:
        row.setValue(where_c)
        updates.updateRow(row)        
    if (row[0].upper() != 'y'):
        row.deleteRow(row)
        print ("NAME")
        row = update.next()

selectSchools(work,sType,outFile)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the error message in full including line numbers.

Comment: I suggest you make a sample dataset of a few records and then trim down your code to just the cursor and see if it works.  It looks to me like you're mixing the different cursor types.  I recommend using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` rather than `arcpy.UpdateCursor()`.  See [ArcGIS Desktop Help - Update Cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

Comment: your `if (row[0].upper() != 'y'):` block should be indented further

Comment: `if (row[0].upper() != 'y'):` will always result in `true` as `y` is not uppercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense to me, but this is what I *think* you are trying to do.

1. Creates new shapefile based on `query`
2. Update Cursor runs on new shapefile
3. If `VERIFIED` field value isn't `Y` or `y` then print the `NAME` and then delete the record

This code snippet may help you get going

```
outFile = "output.shp"
fc = "Schools.shp"

sType = "JUNIOR HIGH"
query = """ "FACILITY" = '{0}' """.format(sType)
arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, outFile, query)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFile, ['FACILITY', 'VERIFIED', 'NAME']) as uCursor:
    for row in uCursor:
        if row[1].upper() != 'Y':
            print row[2]
            uCursor.deleteRow()
```